# IS there any way to get built-in functions in Cplus plus like matlab? or Do I have to implement all the algorithms?

Tags: c++

in matlab I can invert a square matrix with inv (matrix)...in C++ is there any way to do it?

I have a lower triangular matrix.I can invert it in matlab using inv(matrix).But how do I do that in C++?

Comment: Did you try Googling for existing libraries?

Comment: check this link maybe useful https://savingyoutime.wordpress.com/2009/09/21/c-matrix-inversion-boostublas/

Answer (score 1):

two options:you may write it yourself or use open source one:
for matrix see: [Good Matrix Libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11066925/good-matrix-libraries)